# javascript - how do I call a function already bound to a click event

Tags: javascript

I have a div set, and have bound a function, to the click event of that div.

```
$("#my_div").click(function(){
    //do something 
 });
```

Later - I decided I wanted to use the "//**do something**" - for something else too.

Can I call that bound function - some way - other than clicking the element it is bound to?

Thanks.

Comment: Just call it where ever you want like this, DoSomething();

Comment: put the //do something code into another function, and call it.

Comment: `$("#my_div").trigger("click");`

Comment: No other way to call the bound function? Like:
 $("#my_div").click(function SomeFuncName(){});
 OR 
var MyVar = $("#my_div").click(function(){}); 
??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this :

```
function doSomething()
{
 //...
}

$("#my_div").click(function(){
    doSomething();
 });
```

Now , doSomething is free to your future uses.

Comment: or even just `$("#my_div").click(doSomething)`

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes. He might want to _add_ something in the future and still use the granularity of _doSomething_ hence the block.

Answer (score -1):

You can trigger the event like this

`$("#my_div").click();`

whenever you want.

Comment: This **does** answer the question. OP has the code inside the click event function. Triggering the click will execute the code.

Comment: @johnnyRose `$("#my_div").click();` is how to reuse the contents of that click listener.

Comment: @Popnoodles my bad - I misunderstood. Interesting approach for sure.

Comment: This approach (equivalent to `.trigger('click')`) is widely used and is very useful, especially as you can create your own event names, e.g. let's say you had several items that contain a video and a play button. `$('.videowrapper').on('playvideo', function(){/*etc*/});` sets up a reusable event that could be triggered using `$('.play').closest('.videowrapper').trigger('playvideo')` or elsewhere.